# Custom attribute selector not working in IE11

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-11

Does anyone know why the custom attribute selector is not working in IE11 or is there any other alternative to select custom attributes?
My code which works on Chrome:

```
$("[aria-label='" + tempSearchString + "']")
        .parent()
        .css({
          "background-color": "#ae924d",
          "color": "white",
          "cursor": "pointer"
});
```

I also tried it with a filter but it didn't seem to work in IE:

```
$("abbr").filter("[aria-label='" + tempSearchString + "']")
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with the code you provide. I made a sample [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/hvc519nm/) and it works well in IE 11. Have you used F12 dev tools to check if there's any error in console in IE 11? How do you get the `tempSearchString`? I suggest that you can also provide the related html code and made [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce** the issue. So that we can have a test and see how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in React library that I was using which created those custom attributes and it put some "invisible" characters at the beginning/end of the custom attribute. When I was comparing strings of `tempSearchString` and attribute that I was trying to catch they looked the same in writing but [Text Compare](https://text-compare.com/) still found a difference. I decided not to use this library and wrote my own code for that problem.